# regular expression text merge

Tags: php, javascript

Is this possible in reg-ex?

> subject='fox';
>   adjective='quick brown';
>   verb='jumps';
>   text='The <<adjective>> <<subject>> <<verb>> over the lazy dog.'

*reg-ex would return:*

> 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'

Comment: Isn't this just string concatenation?

Comment: No. the text could be from a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need regular expressions to do that. I assume PHP has a string.Replace function of some sort, right? So wouldn't you just be doing (in C#, sorry):

```
text = "The <<adjective>> <<subject>> <<verb>> over the lazy dog.";
text = text.Replace("<<adjective>>", adjective);
text = text.Replace("<<subject>>", subject);
text = text.Replace("<<verb>>", verb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex only when you need to. In this case, you don't:

```
var subject='fox';
var adjective='quick brown';
var verb='jumps';
var text='The <<adjective>> <<subject>> <<verb>> over the lazy dog.'

text = text.replace('<<adjective>>', adjective)
    .replace('<<subject>>', subject)
    .replace('<<verb>>', verb);

console.log(text);
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WmJdP/)**

There's no need to use regex for a simple string replace (regex is quite a bit more expensive than native string functions).

Answer (score 0):

look into look into regex replace

You can probably find what you are looking for [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html)